# How to instantiate new object when using Entity Framework and DDD?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I'm writing a reasonably 'pure' DDD application.  Am not using CQRS.  Persistence is an infrastructure service using EF6.

Now, let's say I have some method that needs to create a new entity of type A and add it to some other entity (B)'s navigation property collection.  That method would be somewhere in the domain assembly, or maybe in the application services assembly.

If I was writing a small app, I'd just call the DBSet.Create method, to ensure I got a reference to proxy object (am using lazy loading), which I could then add to the B's navigation property.

However, given that my Application and Domain assemblies are blissfully unaware that I'm using EF for my persistence, how do I ensure that I don't break lazy-loading?  If I just call A's constructor then I don't have a proxy object.  Should I deal with that fact in my application service (feels all wrong), or maybe make the constructor protected, then pass in a factory to the domain/application services in question?

Edit: Am I doing it all wrong?  Perhaps I can reduce/eliminate my problem as follows:

- I'm used to being able to add to a navigation collection in EF, save, then have the other end of the collection populated for me.  However, in DDD, at creation time, I guess I should populate both ends of any relationship the new entity has?  This would eliminate my navigation issues.
- Would I still need a proxy object?  I'm guessing not, in most cases.  No need to fetch anything from the DB until the transaction that persists a new entity has happened.
- If I was trying to keep the lifetime of the DBContext beyond just the Create (Insert) transaction, then I would either need to have my persistence layer add the new entity to the DBContext (that would mean tracking which ones had been created), or pass in the DBContext's DBSet.Create method as the constructor function for the factory to use.

Comment: Why do you need a proxy object for a new entity? It is just about to be inserted. In my opinion it can be in the application services or in domain, it depends. For example if the new object is part of an aggregate, then the aggregate is responsible for creating.

Comment: Hi, thanks.  You need a proxy object to avoid null reference exceptions on collections.  It almost doesn't matter why, it's more about how do I prevent these persistence concerns from leaking 'up' to domain.  I think the answer has to be a passed-in factory, that's used by the Application Services.

Comment: When you want to create a new entity of type A and add it to some other entity (B)'s navigation property collection, just do it. The domain remains still persistence ignorant, you do not need lazy loading because it is not in the database, EF will insert it when you call SaveChanges.

Comment: Yes, the problem occurs after that.  If I have called the entities constructor, then done as you say, then SaveChanges, I do not have a reference to a proxy object.  That's where lazy loading can break.

Comment: Since most ORMs rely on null collection property to trigger lazy loading, you could avoid accessing ORM managed collection properties from consuming code when possible. (For consumer code usage, create a complement GetCollection() method to access the collection. The method should check for the null property and return an empty collection if needed.)  Some may argue that this leaks persistence implementation into the domain a bit, and you're not 100% protected from falling outside this pattern, but it'll keep collection access behavior consistent if you decouple from EF

Comment: The B's navigation property collection has already been loaded (with your already existing proxies). You add A (that was created with the new keyword). After that point where is the possibility when lazy loading can "break"? If you could extend the question it would be helpful to understand the problem.

Comment: @jannagy02 - My interpretation of the issue is.. If you create a new object outside of EF (vs performing a Create() within the DataContext), the ICollections<> properties within the domain object will be null since it's not an EF proxy object. Therefore consuming code of those collections may need to be aware of that possibility, or something has to be done within the object to make it behave consistently regardless of origin. When you add it and save, it's managed. But until then, the lazy collections aren't proxied.

Comment: Yes.  As well as other lazy navigation properties.

Comment: @Chalky can you include code to illustrate your exact problem? EF has a number of peculiarities related to proxied vs "pristine" objects - it's not really clear which one you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue that I see with your

> reasonably 'pure' DDD application

is that your persistence precedes everything else. If you remember the blue book and its patterns, like Factory to create aggregates, the reason to have these is to create domain objects in valid state. It has nothing to do with persistence.

The persistence logic is better placed in your repositories. The domain should do what it supposes to do - the domain logic. Persistence should take care that your domain model somehow persists. Fine if you choose EF - just do proper mappings and be aware of Impedance Mismatch. However, before you call `repository.Add(myNewAggregate)` there is little sense to think about EF internals.

If you are interested in an example of a simplified, stereotypical implementation of some DDD tactical patterns using EF, you find one below.

Disclaimer: I have just written it, not tested with actual database. No identity handling, no configuration of IoC/DI, no transactions. But I hope you get the idea. EF is just a way to implement these interfaces, with a few lines of code it can be NHibernate, Marten, RavenDb or something else.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace SomeStuff
{
    public interface IAggregateRoot
    {
        int Id { get; }
    }

    public interface IRepository<T> where T : IAggregateRoot
    {
        IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; }
        void Add(T entity);
        T Load(int id);
    }

    public interface IUnitOfWork
    {
        void Commit();
    }

    public class EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        public EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork(DbContext context)
        {
            Context = context;
        }

        public DbContext Context { get; }

        public void Commit() => Context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public class EntityFrameworkRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IAggregateRoot
    {
        private readonly DbSet<T> _set;
        public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; }

        public EntityFrameworkRepository(EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _set = unitOfWork.Context.Set<T>();
        }

        public void Add(T entity) => _set.Add(entity);

        public T Load(int id) => _set.Find(id);

        protected IQueryable<T> Query(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter) => _set.Where(filter);
    }

    public class Employee : IAggregateRoot
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; private set; }

        private Employee(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public static Employee Create(string name) =>
            new Employee(name);

        public void AssignToDepartment(int departmentId) => DepartmentId = departmentId;
    }

    public interface IEmployeeRepository : IRepository<Employee>
    {
        IEnumerable<Employee> AllEmployeesForDepartment(int departmentId);
    }

    public class EmployeeRepository : EntityFrameworkRepository<Employee>, IEmployeeRepository
    {
        public EmployeeRepository(EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork unitOfWork) : base(unitOfWork)
        {
        }

        public IEnumerable<Employee> AllEmployeesForDepartment(int departmentId) =>
            Query(e => e.DepartmentId == departmentId);
    }

    public class EmployeeService
    {
        private readonly IEmployeeRepository _repository;

        public EmployeeService(IEmployeeRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        public void RegisterEmployee(string name)
        {
            var employee = Employee.Create(name);
            _repository.Add(employee);
            _repository.UnitOfWork.Commit();
        }

        public void AssignEmployeeToDepartment(int employeeId, int departmentId)
        {
            var employee = _repository.Load(employeeId);
            if (employee == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Employee not found");

            employee.AssignToDepartment(departmentId);
            _repository.UnitOfWork.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't really address my question.

Comment: Well, if you remove references to domain-driven design, you probably get answers that apply to your question in a way you want...

Comment: Thanks, so looking at the code you've posted, you're saying don't have navigation properties at all.  I appreciate the answer, and I do think this is one, valid approach, but my question is about how to do navigation properties.

Comment: Think twice before going to the land of lazy loading. Many went there and have not return.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this scenario you don't need to deal with navigation at all.

Bring from persistence one aggregate root that deals with the creation of the item and just persist the new item. Like Vaughn Vernon [said](https://vaughnvernon.co/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/DDD_COMMUNITY_ESSAY_AGGREGATES_PART_1.pdf):

```
 public void planProductBacklogItem(String aProductId,String aSummary, String aCategory, String aBacklogItemType) {

//aggregate root with enough info to create the item and check rules
 Product product = productRepository.productOfId(aProductId);

//Create the item. Assign procutID to new backlogitem. Also check rules (max planed items? wrong itemType for this product?, etc...)
 BacklogItem plannedBacklogItem = product.planBacklogItem(aSummary,aBacklogItemType,aCategory);

//just persist the new item. As it has a reference to productID everything goes OK.
 backlogItemRepository.add(plannedBacklogItem);

}
```

Now, to implement this with EF Vernon choose to use [domain object backed by a state object](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=879).